# Conflitos ao carregar o pacote dplyr no R

Tags: r, dplyr

Estou com problema ao carregar o pacote `dplyr`. Quando insiro `library(dplyr)`, aparace esta mensagem:

```
Attaching package: ‘dplyr’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:stats’:

filter, lag

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
```

> Warning message:
> package ‘dplyr’ was built under R version 3.4.4

Como faço para resolver este problema?

Answer (score 1):

Não são mensagens de erro, apenas alertas. O dplyr está avisando que possui comandos com esses nomes, e que há comandos com os mesmos nomes nos pacotes "stats" e "base".

Para, por exemplo, usar o lag do "base" (e não do dplyr), use pacote::comando, dessa maneira:

```
base::lag
```